# Wordpress Website Hack

Tags: php, passwords, wordpress

i have a website in Wordpress Please take a look

> http://www.soulspectrum.org

Now Problem is that sometimes it was hacked by some another one . it happens two times.they change my wordpress admin password and made changes in Index file.

Does AnyBody have an idea how to resolve this. Is there is any Plugin for that

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Pablo: the WP-HackFree Plugin (TM), of course.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest version of WordPress? There may be security vulnerabilities in old versions that could be exploited. A plugin is not necessary to keep WordPress secure...

Comment: Bad people, @RahulBansal. Probably the same ones who hacked your site!

Comment: @ObscureRobot Not Sure Again One more vote Down :P

Comment: @jli: yes i am using latest one

Comment: It might be an exploit in other software you have then. Check your webserver for updates, your php version, mysql, anything else you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for this, such as:

- You don't have an upto date wordpress installation, so there might be security vulnerabilities in it.
- Your admin password is not strong enough.
- You may have upload forms in your site which allows someone to upload any kind of file, the hacker may upload a script file and run that from browser navigation bar to run the malicious script.
- It might be due to no tight security from the hosting provider.

There can be many things. You may want to check out [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) post from codex itself.

Comment: +1 on all counts. Also check plugins, not all plugins are built with the highest consideration to security..

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress being an open ended, developer rich community lends itself to being hacked in as many ways as platform can be. Though the core developers are actually some of the stronger minds in the industry, the developers that make plugins are often not. They could be fresh out of school, or hobos off the street. There's no regulation per say, so any plugin you install could potentially be a weak point for your site and anything else on your file server.

The best advise I can give is to keep your WP version current by using the built in utility in your admin panel, and just not be a fool with what you plug in to your site. If you are a programmer, audit the plugin before enabling it. If you are not a programmer, then you kind of have to deal with the consequences of taking the quick and easy way out.

This answer could get much more in depth, but the succinct way of responding is to just be aware of what you're plugging in. Google the plugins to see if anyone else has had issues with that particular one.