# Wordpress website hacked and .htaccess file is creating automatically with strange code

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress website .htaccess has some strange redirection script, i removed the file but once the site is browsed the .htaccess file is automatically created with the strange script. in addition to that a folder named generall is also automatically creating even though we delete the folder. The folder has one php file and html file with strange scripts. Please help to resolve the hacking issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress Website Hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059313/wordpress-website-hack)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your website still contains malware. You need to do a complete virus scan. You can use **WordFence** plugin to scan.

With these also try

**1.** Update all theme & plugins.

**2.** Do a manual update of your WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You need to completely remove the infection from your site. Here's the easiest WordPress guide to follow: https://malcure.com/blog/security/the-easiest-guide-to-wordpress-malware-removal/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it.
1-open your index.php file .
2-you might see too many lines of code. delete those codes and just keep the default codes as follows :

```html
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

3-search for htaccess files and delete all of them. you can use Win scp app to connect to your host and search for them.
there should be just a single htaccess file in in the WordPress main directory. replace the hacked htacces file with this codes :

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

4-delete all plugins and themes and replace them with a fresh download.
5-download a fresh copy of WordPress and replace it with the current one (dont worry it wont damage your current files.

6- install WordPress all-in-one security plugin and try to minimize the risk of being hacked again by configuring the plugin.
7- this plugin can scan for malware but I suggest usign an anti-malware and security application called Sucori :https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/. this app connects to your host using ftp credentials and scnas for malware.
8- make sure that you take all the precautions to avoid and hack attacks and malware contamination.
here is the link for you
https://blog.hubspot.com/website/wordpress-security-issues